# Odds ratio calculations general method

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with two variables, gender and town (Df1). I'd like to calculate the odds ratio for gender (with female=1), and I'd like to do so per town so that I end up with a total three odds ratios for Df1.

My actual data set contains many more towns, so I'd like to know if there's a more general way of doing this, than to manually enter the number of observations into epitools::oddsratio()?

Thanks!

Starting point (df):

```
Df1 <- data.frame(gender=c("m","m","m","f","f","f","m","m","m","f","m","f","m","f","f","f","f","f","f","f"), town=c("ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ma","ma","ma","ma","ma","ma"))
```

Code so far:

```
library(epitools)
Df2 <- matrix(c(12,20,8,20),byrow=TRUE,ncol=2)
dimnames(Df2) <- list(Group=c("females","males"),MI=c("subtotal","total"))
oddsratio(Df2)
```

**Note**: Odds Ratio (literally the ratio between two odds)

Assume 7 out of 10 males are admitted: p=0.7, q=1-0.7=0.3

Assume 3 out of 10 females get admitted: p=0.3, q=1-0,3=0.7

Admissions odds for males: 0.7/0.3=2.333 (getting admitted/not getting admitted)

Admissions odds for female: 0.3/0.7=0.429

The odds ratio for admission: OR=2.333/0.429=5.44,

ie the odds of a male being admitted is 5.44 times greater than that for a female.

Comment: What is *odds ratio*? How is it calculated?

Comment: `oddsratio(table(Df1$town, Df1$gender))` gives you three odds ratios, where the first town works as a baseline. Is this what you want?

Comment: epitools::oddsratio(table(Df1$town, Df1$gender)) returns a error for me

Comment: please share the expected output

Comment: Also, say for eg we consider `la`, your data suggests `la` has `5` females and `2` males. how do you get how many of these are `admitted` ?? where is this value coming from?

Comment: @MLEN it returns an error as long as a cell contains no observations. When you edit the data to contain at least one case of the combination `m` + `ma`, the code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
Df1 <- data.frame(gender=c("m","m","m","f","f","f","m","m","m","f","m","f","m","f","f","f","f","f","f","f"), town=c("ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ny","la","ma","ma","ma","ma","ma","ma"))

Df1 %>% group_by(town) %>% summarise(
p_males   = sum(gender == "m")/n(),
p_females = sum(gender == "f")/n(),
odds_males = p_males/p_females,
odds_females = p_females/p_males,
odds_ratio = odds_males/odds_females)
```